# WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org

Tags: wordpress, vagrant

On a fresh Wordpress install, I'm getting:

```
WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org
<http-dir>/wp-includes/update.php on line 295
```

It also happens on every local WP site I have on my dev VM. They were working fine for the last 6+ months.

The VM can access the internet, has ports 80 and 443 open, and is  a VirtualBox Vagrant machine running Ubuntu 14.04. There's nothing more informative in the error logs.

Any ideas what might be going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are accessing through Vagrant, you can edit the hosts file to resolve the IP.

Add below configuration to your your `/etc/hosts` file

```
66.155.40.202 api.wordpress.org
```